# Remove lines containing keyword from a file

Tags: ant

I would like to remove all lines from a textfile which contain a certain keyword.

So far I only found:

```
<linecontains>
    <contains value="assert"/>
</linecontains>
```

but I don't know how to remove those lines.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You would use that filter in a [filterchain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html), in a task which supports the filterchain element, i.e. the built-in Concat, Copy, LoadFile, LoadProperties, Move tasks.

So, for example, copy or move the file using a filterchain containing your linecontains filter.

Use the `negate` parameter on your `linecontains` filter to exclude lines containing that string.

Example:

```
<project default="test">
    <target name="test">
        <copy tofile="file.txt.edit" file="file.txt">
            <filterchain>
                <linecontains negate="true">
                    <contains value="assert"/>
                </linecontains>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Before:

```
$ cat file.txt
abc
assert
def
assert
ghi assert
jkl
```

After:

```
$ cat file.txt.edit
abc
def
jkl
```

To answer your followup question on applying to selected files in a directory:

```
<copy todir="dest">
    <fileset dir="src">
        <include name="**/*.txt"/>
    </fileset>
    <filterchain>
        <linecontains negate="true">
            <contains value="assert"/>
        </linecontains>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Comment: thanks, one more question: how could i apply this to a whole directory and check for certain file types? for example i want to do this to all txt files but not to jpg files of course.

Comment: Use a [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) in the copy to specify the files you want to include.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute an external command.

I haven't tested but on UNIX you might run something like this:

```
<exec executable="sed">
    <arg value="s/assert//" />
   <arg value="YOUR_FILE" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Doesn't `s/assert//` only remove the word assert, not its whole line?